# What is the difference in Captain Price's looks from MW1 and MW2?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

What are the differences of Captain Price' looks and actions across the first two Modern Warfare games?

Comment: I don't recall exactly, but wasn't Captain Price never seen or heard in MW1, only played in first person perspective? It's difficult to compare differences when you haven't actually seen the guy to begin with.

Comment: No, only one mission is first-person. In all other missions, Price is a NPC and can be seen.

Comment: Correction, two missions in CoD4: MW. 'All Ghillied Up' and 'One Shot, One Kill' provide Price as the playable character.

Answer (score 4):

Not much changed in his appearance from all 3 games. Of course his appearance may change from mission to mission based on the environment, but his overall looks did not really change. He retains his distinctive facial hair and floppy hat throughout all 3 games. You can read about Price and see different images here:
http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/John_Price
http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/John_Price/Gallery

Here is Price in Modern Warfare 1:

[image: Price, MW1]

Here is Price in Modern Warfare 2:

[image: Price, MW2]

And here is Price in Modern Warfare 3:

[image: Price, MW3]

As you can see, not much difference, but you should be able to spot any differences from these pictures. Hope this helps.